# SQL Server nested loop

Tags: sql-server, left-join

i have a query and when i use  set statistics profile on on it, it show this

```
294395  1--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, 
OUTER REFERENCES:([db].[dbo].[PVPG].[PVPG_PRVE_Ide]) OPTIMIZED)
```

My question: how can I improve performance on it.
There is an Index on it :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FK_PVPG_PRVE_PRVE_IDE] ON [dbo].[PVPG] 
(
    [PVPG_PRVE_Ide] ASC
)
```

Index Scan Density and Logical Scan Fragmentation are ok.

statistics are OK.

i can provide more detail if need like the whole query

thanks for help

Comment: Please post the entire query.

Comment: There is zero chance anybody can help here because you haven't posted any details. At the very least we need to see the query, the table definitions and indexes. Otherwise it is a crap shoot.

Answer (score 0):

here you'll find two scripts :

[Query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl6tu6i1nrpgst5/query.sql?dl=0)

[Tables definition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd0mu8jlj7lwcij/table_definition.sql?dl=0)